# Drag and clone MovieClip in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have a toolbar with some cars on the left of the window, and I want to click on one element and drag it to the board creating a clone of it, but I can't do it.

My app looks like this:

[image]

Cars on the left are my desired dragged.

My source code is:

```
public class Car extends MovieClip
    {

        // imports...

        var newcar:Car;

        public function Car(){
            addListeners();
        }

        private function addListeners():void{
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,clone);
        }

        private function clone(e:MouseEvent):void{
            // Clone the object
            newcar = new dibujo();
            newcar.graphics.copyFrom(this.graphics);
            newcar.x = this.x;
            this.parent.addChild(newcar);

                    // Asign new events to recently created mc
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,dragCar);
            newcar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,dropCar);
        }

        private function dragCar(e:MouseEvent):void{
            this.startDrag();
        }

        private function dropCar(e:MouseEvent):void{
            this.stopDrag();
        }

    }
```

The red car and the truck use my own basic class called 'Car'.

Thanks in advance! I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And what is not working? 
Main problem I see is, that you create new car, but you don't add it to the display list. In your clone function, you need something like

```
this.parent.addChild(newcar);
```

edit:
So as I said in comments, problem is, tah property graphics is read only, so you can't change it.
If your cars are instaces of classes that extend your Car (if they are not, you can easily make them), you can use this:
replace

```
newcar = new dibujo(); //I think you menat new Car() here
```

with

```
newcar = new e.target.constructor;
```

this should finally make it work.
You will then encounter problem with dragging - it never stops. But solution is simple, add this line to your stopDrag function:

```
e.target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, dragCar);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but didnt work either. Anyways, I traced `this.parent.numChildren` and is increased with every click on the original cars. So, the problem could be relative to drag&drop feature :\

Comment: And did you set y coordinate of new car? In the same way as you set x.

Comment: Yeah, and didnt work either. Maybe the movieclip is created, but with any graphics on it. But still don't know why.

Comment: Strange, I just tested and adding new object to scene works for me perfectly.
There is just issue with the dragging, which is solvable, but even now, I see new car on the scene in my case

Comment: Oh I see! graphics is read only property, so can't copy it like this, sadly I have idea for solution, I will try it a then I'll update my answer